# Set true values list

Tags: java, boolean

So im still learning about classes and I trying to figure out how to use boolean arrays. I have a dice class and I want to create a another class that checks all 1-6 numbers once. For example dice stops rolling when 1-6 has rolled once. Having trouble trying to assigning dice getfaceValue and setValue as true so occurrence numbers are discarded, Also I want to test the BooleanArray class to another new class so 3 classes total. thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class BooleanArray {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Die dice;

        boolean b[];

        b = new boolean[7];
        //ASSIGNING ELEMENTS TO BOOLEAN ARRAY
        b[0] = true;
        b[1] = false;
        b[2] = false;
        b[3] = false;
        b[4] = false;
        b[5] = false;
        b[6] = false;


        dice = new Die();

        dice.roll();
        if (dice.getFaceValue() == b[1]) {
            b[1] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Roll the Dice or Die!

Comment: I have, dice.roll() but im trying to return the dice value with the array value to make true so if arraylist is all true then stop rolling

Comment: @Stacyx9 actually, you do not need to compare value of the array with dice roll result. You need to compare index of the array with dice roll. Example, dice roll = 3, then you should assign to the array[3] =true

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dice.getFaceValue() == int b[1]) {
```

This is a syntax error. The word `int` should not be present. Were you attempting to cast? If so, the syntax is `(int) b[1]` but a boolean cannot be cast to an integer.

If you remove `int` altogether, you are attempting to compare an integer on the left hand side with a boolean on the right hand side which is not possible.

Comment: im trying to compare the dice value and the arraylist value so if getFace equals to 1, compare with b[1] and return true?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need 3 classes: one with main method(starter), Boolean array class and Dice class.

First, lets create Boolean Array class. It will contain your "b" array and will check that all values become true:

```
class BooleanArray {
  boolean b[] = {true, false, false, false, false, false, false};

  // sets value=true to array index from 1 to 6
  void setTrueToIndex(int index){

      // outputs every dice rolled value
      System.out.println(index);

      if(index > 0 && index<b.length){
          b[index] = true;
      }
  }

  // checks that Dice rolled to values 1-6 minimum one time
  boolean checkThatAllTrue(){
      for (boolean value : b) {
          if(value == false){ // possible short-hand if(!value)
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true;
  }
}
```

So, your starter class may be rewritten as:

```
public class DiceGame {
  public static void main(String args[]){
      Die dice = new Die();

      BooleanArray booleanArray = new BooleanArray();

      // counter for dice rolling
      int howManyTimesDiceRolled = 0;

      // we will roll dice until all values will be true
      while(!booleanArray.checkThatAllTrue()){
          int roll = dice.roll();
          howManyTimesDiceRolled++;
          booleanArray.setTrueToIndex(roll);
      }
      System.out.println("Dice rolled: " + howManyTimesDiceRolled);
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Dice number: 4
Dice number: 2
Dice number: 2
Dice number: 2
Dice number: 3
Dice number: 5
Dice number: 4
Dice number: 4
Dice number: 3
Dice number: 6
Dice number: 5
Dice number: 6
Dice number: 1
Dice rolled: 13
```

So, in my system it took Dice to roll 13 times before all values of the array become true.

Comment: is there another way to set each value 1-6 false? i ran the program and its missing numbers. eg output is 10 but missing dice number 4

Comment: Strange. I modified my code to check that dice rolled all values minimum one time System.out.println("Dice number: " + index);
What for do you need to set each value 1-6 false? "For example dice stops rolling when 1-6 has rolled once. " you need to set value to true, not false. False is your default value, symbolizing that dice haven't rolled this number yet.